# Unity 2D: Decrease jump distance without compromising jump height

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can it be done?

Here is the code for my jumping:

```
void FixedUpdate(){
    if(!takingDamage){

        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        body.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, body.velocity.y);

        if (jumping){
            body.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);         
            onGround = false;
        }       
    }

}
```

I already tried tinkering with gravity, reducing the speed, increasing the mass... Everything I do to decrease the distance also decreases the height, but the height is right where I want it to be...

The solution was to check if the character was on the ground when setting the horizontal speed and decreasing the added velocity, here is how the logic is with that change:

```
void FixedUpdate(){
    if(!takingDamage){

        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if(onGround){
            body.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, body.velocity.y);
        } else {
            body.velocity = new Vector2(move * (speed * 0.7f), body.velocity.y);
        }

        if (jumping){
            body.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);         
            onGround = false;
        }       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding an opposite force from their movement, something like "jump drag", where they get slowed down if they try to move horizontally.

I'm assuming you're using AddForce if they move left or right, you could just check if it's jumping, and addForce in the opposite direction to offset.

Another way would be to scale its velocity vector only in the horizontal direction. Something like:

```
newVelocity = new Vector3(oldVelocity.x, oldVelocity.y, oldVelocity.z * scaleFactor)
```

Comment: thanks, you really put me on the right track, I'll edit my answer with the solution I found

Comment: Note that this is 2D so the changes you made in the z-axis should be done in the x-axis but it looks like OP got it and changed it to fix. This comment is for people that will come across this answer.